# C++ Decoration design pattern - Code works but don't know why

Tags: c++, recursion, decorator

This is a sample code showing an example of how the decoration design pattern is used in C++ and although the code looks simple it puzzles me on why it's working properly..

Code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// 1. "lowest common denom"
class Widget
{
  public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class TextField: public Widget
{
    // 3. "Core" class & "is a"
    int width, height;
  public:
    TextField(int w, int h)
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    /*virtual*/
    void draw()
    {
        cout << "TextField: " << width << ", " << height << '\n';
    }
};

// 2. 2nd level base class
class Decorator: public Widget  // 4. "is a" relationship
{
    Widget *wid; // 4. "has a" relationship
  public:
    Decorator(Widget *w)
    {
        wid = w;
    }

    /*virtual*/
    void draw()
    {
        wid->draw(); // 5. Delegation
    }
};

class BorderDecorator: public Decorator
{
  public:
    // 6. Optional embellishment
    BorderDecorator(Widget *w): Decorator(w){}

    /*virtual*/
    void draw()
    {
        // 7. Delegate to base class and add extra stuff
        Decorator::draw();
        cout << "   BorderDecorator" << '\n';
    }
};

class ScrollDecorator: public Decorator
{
  public:
    // 6. Optional embellishment
    ScrollDecorator(Widget *w): Decorator(w){}

    /*virtual*/
    void draw()
    {
        // 7. Delegate to base class and add extra stuff
        Decorator::draw();
        cout << "   ScrollDecorator" << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
  // 8. Client has the responsibility to compose desired configurations
  Widget *aWidget = new BorderDecorator(new BorderDecorator(new ScrollDecorator(new TextField(80, 24))));
  aWidget->draw();
}
```

The output produced:

```
TextField: 80, 24
   ScrollDecorator
   BorderDecorator
   BorderDecorator
```

The part that I don't get is, as far as I can see the code will never reach

```
cout << "   BorderDecorator" << '\n';
cout << "   ScrollDecorator" << '\n';
```

What is the role of the

```
Decorator::draw();
```

It looks like a recursive call.. apologies if my question is a bit cloudy here.

Comment: `Decorator::draw()` explicitly calls the `Draw` function in the parent (`Decorator`) class.

Comment: And to untangle it all, I suggest you use a debugger and step through (and most importantly) into the function calls.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, thanks for your comments, I'm running the debugger right now, observing where it steps into..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a class derived from `Decorator`, the call to `Decorator::draw()` is an explicit invocation of the base class method, even though it is declared as `virtual`.  It is not a recursive call at all, rather it is a way to invoke base class functionality and then add more functionality afterward (or before).

Comment: that's exactly what I mean.. it calls for wid -> draw() . Wouldn't this recursively call the draw() in either BorderDecorator or ScrollDecorator? Which is... recursive..

Comment: @lukieleetronic: Ultimately `wid->draw()` ends up in `TextField::draw()`.

Comment: Ah...ran the debugger several times, I think I'm getting it.. To be frank, I should have re-phrased my question to "how is the calling of Decorator::draw() traverses all the way to the TextField::draw()" this was the part I didn't fully understand.